# Changing images by mouse scroll and timer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code that changes images by mouse scroll, I need to add an automatic change of images if the user does not scroll within 7 seconds

```
<script>
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
let currentIndexScroll = 0;
let isScrolling = false;
let hasScrolled = false;

function getRandomIndex(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    if (isScrolling) return;

    const delta = e.deltaY;
    const sensitivity = 40;

    if (delta > sensitivity && !hasScrolled) {
        currentIndexScroll = getRandomIndex(images.length);
        hasScrolled = true;
    } else if (delta < -sensitivity && !hasScrolled) {
        currentIndexScroll = getRandomIndex(images.length);
        hasScrolled = true;
    }

    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        if (index === currentIndexScroll) {
            image.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            image.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    });

    if (hasScrolled) {
        isScrolling = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            isScrolling = false;
            hasScrolled = false;
        }, 600);
    }
});
</script>
```

I tried to add a timer, but the images do not change

Comment: First of, don't use `setTimeout` within a scroll `"wheel"` event callback. Even if you use a boolean flag the code is hard to reason about. Use `clearTimeout` instead. Define your functions outside of the wheel event and use them as necessary

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, I'm new to JS, can you help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Also, avoid the use of `Element.style` in JS as much as you can. Instead use a CSS *modifier* class like `.is-active {` and style accordingly. In JS then, use `imageElem.classList.toggle("is-active", booleanState)` instead.

Comment: Also, makes no sense to have two exact chunks of code both in the `if` and `else` statement (the `currentIndexScroll = getRandomIndex(images.length); hasScrolled = true;`)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wćhy do you assign `document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {` on the document? If your app increases in size your page will also scroll vertically since you did not used `Event.preventDefault()` and assigned a listener to the images wrapper parent. OK, this all depends on your UI, but hard to tell without seeing a [mcve] of what you're actually building.

Comment: Also, by using `Math.random()` you're running into the possibility of the same image index being generated again, leading to a seemingly broken UX. I'd rather suggest you use the modulo (reminder) operator `%` to loop over the images from the beginning.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I got this code from a previous developer who worked on this project. I am a Webflow developer and don’t understand much about js, but the client asked me to add an automatic change of pictures and I don’t know what to do.

Comment: OK, will provide you with a nice sample suggestion soon!

Comment: PS: since you have not, make sure to read: [tour].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you very much, this is practically what I need, the only scroll on my site is not performed on the image itself and therefore the scroll code does not work
https://www.valkyrie.wtf/new-website/home - that`s my site, 
this is how scrolling is done now with the old code

Comment: Oh, I get i now. Will edit my answer soon

Comment: Then, instead of `elParent.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);` just use: `addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you very much, everything works great

Comment: Oh, glad to hear! You're very welcome Yana

Comment: Hi, @RokoC.Buljan I have a little problem with your code, when I do a swipe on the touchpad there is a problem with changing pictures. Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: Sorry, not a swipe, problem with touchpad scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reusable example which uses setInverval to **autoplay** your images on init, and if the mouse is not hovering the images parent.  Uses the Modulo operator `%` in a `mod` function to loop over the images. Uses simple functions like `anim()` that animates assigning an *active* class to the `c` *current index* image. Uses `next()` and `prev()` functions on "wheel" event to increment or decrement `c` *current index* and `anim()` animate to the *current* image. As a bonus, on click calls the `next()` function:

```js
// DOM utility functions:
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Utility functions:
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m; // Fix negative Modulo


// Images wheeler component:
const imagesWheeler = (elParent) => {

  const elsImages = els(".image", elParent);
  const tot = elsImages.length;
  let itv = null;
  let c = 0; // current index

  const anim = () => {
    elsImages.forEach((elImage, i) => {
      elImage.classList.toggle("is-active", i === c);
    });
  };

  const next = () => {
    c = mod(++c, tot);
    anim();
  };

  const prev = () => {
    c = mod(--c, tot);
    anim();
  };

  const play = () => {
    itv = setInterval(next, 3000);
  };
  
  const stop = () => {
    clearInterval(itv);
  };

  const handleWheel = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    c += Math.sign(evt.deltaY); // get 1, -1
    c = mod(c, tot);
    anim();
  };

  // Events:
  elParent.addEventListener("pointerenter", stop);
  elParent.addEventListener("pointerleave", play);
  elParent.addEventListener("pointerdown", next);
  addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);

  // Init:
  anim(); // animate to first image
  play(); // start autoplay!

};

els(".images-container").forEach(imagesWheeler);
```

```css
.images-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  
  &>* {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    aspect-ratio: inherit;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    
    &.is-active {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Use click to advance, wheel to prev/next, mouseleave to autoplay!

<div class="images-container">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/01/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/02/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/03/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/04/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/05/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/06/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/07/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/08/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/09/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/10/200/200" alt="">
</div>

<p>Hey, you can have multiple!</p>

<div class="images-container">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/21/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/22/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/23/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/24/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/25/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/26/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/27/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/28/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/29/200/200" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/seed/30/200/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo-code below:

```js
let timer = setInterval(scroll, 7000);

function scroll(
  if(!hasScrolled){
    // code to scroll the image here.
    
    
    hasScrolled = true;
  }
);
```